# vNext redirect to login return 404

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I am using vNext and it runs well ok localhost but on the server the redirect to login feature does send me to the correct url (XXX/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FMonitoring) but I get an error message.

```
404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

The method:

```
[HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {            
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;

            return View();
        }
```

Startup.cs

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
                options.AutomaticChallenge = true;
                options.AuthenticationScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;                
                options.CookieName = "WnctAuthCookie";
                if (!env.IsDevelopment())
                    options.CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always;
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60); 
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login");
                options.LogoutPath = new PathString("/Account/Logout");
            });
```

I am using `1.0.0-rc1-final` and I am also using IIS 7.5 under Windows 7 and I have https enabled.

I'm not sure weather this is due to a setting on IIS or something else. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: does navigate directly to  "/Monitor"  work?

Comment: @Thorarins after you login, otherwise it redirects to login and returns 404

Comment: so it is login that it cant find ?

Comment: @Thorarins login works but not with returnUrl, then it returns 404

Comment: Can you post a repro on github?

Comment: @MagnusKarlsson It seems that the problem is it does not redirect to https

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu Add a [RequireHttps] attribute to the controller.

Comment: @MagnusKarlsson already tried and I get an error on the server: too many redirects (something like that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but i think you have to enter file name with it's extension Like this

```
  options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login.aspx");
  options.LogoutPath = new PathString("/Account/Logout.aspx");
```

Comment: the problem seems to be it does not redirect to https